# How to obtain a specific number's previous and next number in Python while using string, integer, print and input only?

Tags: python

I'm new to coding and just wondering how to obtain a number's previous and next number in Python by only using string, integer, print and input.

Comment: this is unclear to me what you are asking for...please provide a code example and what's missing

Answer (score 1):

You may use:

```
n= 9
print("Prev: " + str(n-1) + " Current: " + str(n) + " Next: " + str(n+1))
```

Answer (score 1):

like this :

```
number = int(input("enter a number: "))
previous_number = number - 1 
next_number = number + 1
print(f"previous number: {previous_number}\n"
      f"next number: {next_number}")
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use this:

```
n=int(input())  ## use of input and integer
print("previous number: " + str(n-1))  ## use of print and string
print("number: " + str(n))
print("next number: " + str(n+1))
```

Output when input = 4:

```
previous number: 3
number: 4
next number: 5
```

Answer (score 1):

```
n = int(input())
print(n - 1, n + 1)
# or
print("{0} {1}".format(n - 1, n + 1))
# or
print(f"{n - 1} {n + 1}")
```

There are uncountable amounts to do what you want.
Look around, good luck for your learning.